# Grunt & Lineman - run task with parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, gruntjs, linemanjs

Is it possible to parametrize already existing grunt task? F.e. there is a 
[pages task](https://github.com/linemanjs/lineman/blob/master/tasks/pages.coffee) where I would like to add some additional actions based on my custom parameter. I've been trying to add something like that in my **application.js**

```
...
pages: {
    dev: {
        someParam: true
    }
},
...
```

and printing it inside pages.coffee:

```
grunt.registerMultiTask "pages", "generates static HTML files", (someParam) ->
grunt.log.writeln("#{someParam}"); //prints undefined
```

So it looks like the matter of passing value to task: what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it: inside pages.coffee:

```
taskConfig = grunt.config.get("pages")
grunt.log.writeln("${taskConfig.someParam}")
```

Generally if you would like to override some already defined variables Lineman uses (f.e. source/destination folders) I suggest you to look into `node_modules/{module_name}/config/plugins`. After analyzing those files you can easily figure out the way how to override some properties (very similar to what I've done in my initial post).